# Rebasing specific part of git history

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

Is it possible (with a rebase I guess) to get this

```
<lots of commit above>
* 54dda... commit d 
* 78adf... commit c
* 65d3aa0 .. branch commit 3
* 404b9cf .. branch commit 2
* 77e8a38 .. branch commit 1
* e239d7... commit b
* 78azee... commit a
<lots of commit below>
```

from this

```
<lots of commit above>
* 54dda... commit d 
* 78adf... commit c
|\
| * 65d3aa0 .. branch commit 3
| * 404b9cf .. branch commit 2
| * 77e8a38 .. branch commit 1
|/
* e239d7... commit b
* 78azee... commit a
<lots of commit below>
```

Comment: No.  The hash of a commit depends on all of its ancestors. The commit with message "commit c" with one parent is very different than the merge commit that creates the same tree.  It will have a different hash.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are asking if you can generate that graph but in which several of the hashes differ, then the answer is "yes".

Comment: `git rebase e239d7` should do the job. By default, rebase flattens commits by removing merge commits (if I'm not mistaken, `78adf` would be gone). Of course, all downstream commit hashes will change, so you have to understand the implications.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
git checkout 78adf
git reset --soft 65d3aa0
git commit -m 'commit C'
# same content as 78adf, but it's not a merge anymore.... auhor/committet are you (dates adjusted as well)
# then replay whatever was on top of it
git cherry-pick 78adf..whatever-branch
# if you like the result, set a branch over here
git checkout -b some-branch
```